# Class WeatherBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)

Tags: apex, batch

```
global class WeatherBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{
     String query;
global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<String, Object> records) {
        List<Weather_Forecast__c> forecast = new List<Weather_Forecast__c>();

        for (List<String, Object> record : records) {
            forecast.add(
                buildforecast(record)
            );

        }
     insert forecasts;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called as `List<string,Object>` in apex.

Replace your below code

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<String, Object> records)
```

with

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> records)
```

Signature for execute method is

```
public Void execute(Database.BatchableContext jobId, List<sObject> recordList)
```

So it takes `Database.BatchableContext` and `List<sObject>` as parameters, whereas in your code your execute methods takes incorrect values. You can learn more about batch classes at [Batchable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm) documentation.